# When i try to send email from gmail to mailinator recipients . I am only able to send mails to first 15 mailgun recipients

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, gmail

When I try to send emails from Gmail to mailinator recipients. I am only able to send mails to first 15 mailgun recipients and if I exceed more than that then I get an error like [image]

I don't know how to handle this. I tried to change execution time also but it's not working.

```
max_execution_time=180
```

Comment: There is a number of places in PHP this can be configured. You could try setting in the PHP config.

Comment: ok..thanks.. but I tried both max_execution_time and max_input_time but not working will need to optimize the script maybe.

Comment: @benjaminhull actually max_input_time was causing it. I tried after restarting server and it's working fine now. thanks again